# CSS :link and :visited not working

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, visited

I'm having one very difficult time getting :link and :visited to work on my  links. I have been searching online for literally hours and read over 20 different instances of the same problem. Bizarrely enough, :hover and :active are working. What is going on?

Here's the code lines in my stylesheet:

```
H1 { text-align: center; width:1000px; font-size: 30pt; font-weight: bold; }

a.artlinks:link {color:#40C0FF; text-decoration: none; font-family: Cambria, Arial; }

a.artlinks:visited { color:#FF00FF; text-decoration: none; font-family: Cambria, Arial; }

a.artlinks:hover {color:#98D7F6; text-decoration: none; font-family: Cambria, Arial; }

a.artlinks:active {color:#FF0000; text-decoration: none; font-family: Cambria, Arial; }
```

and when I call it in my .html the code is:

```
<h1><a href="helloworld.html" class="artlinks">Hello World!</a></h1>
```

Does anyone have a solution and also, a more efficient way to give the common a.artlinks parameters simultaneously? Thanks

Comment: Use proper html! `code` <H1><a CLASS="artlinks" href="helloworld.html"> helloworld </a> </H1> `code`

Comment: link worked for me. - http://jsfiddle.net/n0qo7ybp/1/

Comment: kasper why don't you tell me how to actually insert html tags since when I wrote out my post it was displaying the literal word "hello world" instead of the code

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs a bit of a tidy up, but this is how I would do it (edit I removed the width property from the h1 for demonstration purposes).

```
H1 { 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 30pt; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}

a.artlinks {
    text-decoration: none; 
    font-family: Cambria, Arial;
    color:#40C0FF;
}

a.artlinks:visited { 
    color:#FF00FF; 
}

a.artlinks:hover {
    color:#98D7F6; 
}

a.artlinks:active {
    color:#FF0000; 
}
```

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/zkb8thck/

As the a class has the same properties, you can define those once in a.artlinks (font-family, text-decoration). The other elements that are unique can then be defined for :hover, :active etc.

Comment: i still dont see the magenta color showing up for visited state.

Comment: @pjp try the second link in the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/zkb8thck/1/

Comment: duh me! for the visited to work, the link has to point to resource which the browser has already might have VISITED.

Comment: After some experimentation wtih changin :visited color it appears my entire problem was due to browser cache/history on my links. But thanks for the clarification on class properties; I didn't think css had such structuring